# Reset Spring Boot Kafka Stream Application on modifying topics

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I'm using a `spring-kafka` to run Kafka Stream in a Spring Boot application using `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`. I changed the number of partitions in some of the topics from 100 to 20 by deleting and recreating them, but now on running the application, I get the following error:

```
Existing internal topic MyAppId-KSTREAM-AGGREGATE-STATE-STORE-0000000092-changelog has invalid partitions: expected: 20; actual: 100. Use 'kafka.tools.StreamsResetter' tool to clean up invalid topics before processing.
```

I couldn't access the class `kafka.tools.StreamsResetter` and tried calling `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean.getKafkaStreams.cleanup()` but it gave `NullPointerException`. How do I do the said cleanup?

Comment: As describe in the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant documentation is at [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+Streams+Application+Reset+Tool).

#### Step 1: Local Cleanup

For Spring Boot with `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean`, the first step can be done by simply adding `CleanerConfig` to the constructor:

```java
// Before
new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(config));
// After
new StreamsBuilderFactoryBean(new KafkaStreamsConfiguration(config), new CleanupConfig(true, true));
```

This enables calling the `KafkaStreams.cleanUp()` method on both before `start()` & after `stop()`.

#### Step 2: Global Cleanup

For step two, with all instances of the application stopped, simply use the tool as explained in the documentation:

```sh
# In kafka directory
bin/kafka-streams-application-reset.sh --application-id "MyAppId" --bootstrap-servers 1.2.3.4:9092 --input-topics x --intermediate-topics first_x,second_x,third_x --zookeeper 1.2.3.4:2181
```

What this does:

> For any specified input topics: Reset the application’s committed consumer offsets to "beginning of the topic" for all partitions (for consumer group application.id).
>
> For any specified intermediate topics: Skip to the end of the topic, i.e. set the application’s committed consumer offsets for all partitions to each partition’s logSize (for consumer group application.id).
>
> For any internal topics: Delete the internal topic (this will also delete committed the corresponding committed offsets).